# Why does it appear that my Javascript code is a comment?

Tags: javascript, comments, dreamweaver

Here is my code:

```
chart.fillText(i*topNum, (right_cordinates_width/3)*2, (cVid.height-line_bottom_distance) / 10 - i );
```

the characters between **/** `/3)*2, (cVid.height-line_bottom_distance) /`
is grayed out like a comment.

Why does this happen and is it really a comment?

Comment: What makes you think that code is commented?

Comment: i don't know but it turns ing gray @ssube

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by "commented"? Where? When? Is this in some editor or something?

Comment: I think he means syntax highlighting, and it is probably detecting a regex pattern (/ ... /) in error.

Comment: "i use dreamweaver"   Hey, there's your problem!   (i've seen it do braindead things like this  with syntax before)

Comment: @BadZen So you are saying this is because of dreamweaver

Comment: Well, `/something/` is used for regex in javascript. If dreamweaver isn't smart enough to realize that you're just trying to divide things, I say it's about time you stop using dreamweaver. I never had that problem with Notepad++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a highlighting error. This comes from your code editor or IDE.
It could be a good reason for switching to an other one. (Or search if this is a bug of the editor/IDE you are using)